# How to get data in database and display specific data in View (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am a newbie to Codeigniter framework, I have created a simple app that will fetch data from database and then display with condition in Views. I'm trying to display specific data from database to my View, So far, I have no luck using the code below.

Model (Datamodel.php)

```
function getData() {
    $this->db->select("name, value");
    $this->db->from('settings');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller (maincontroller.php)

```
function index()
{
    $data['metadata'] = $this->Datamodel->getData();
    $this->load->view('viewdata', $data);
}
```

View

```
  <h3>Site Information</h3>
  <?php foreach($metadata as $data) {?>
      <h4>Site Title: <?php echo $data['site_title']; ?></h4>
      <h4>Site Description: <?php echo $data['site_description']; ?></h4>
      <h4>Site keyword: <?php echo $data['site_keyword']; ?></h4>
      <h4>Site Year: <?php echo $data['site_year']; ?></h4>
  <?php }?>
```

I want to display something like these on browser:

#### Site Information

Site Title: My first codeigniter app
Site Description: This is sample ci application
Site keyword: simple ci app, first app
Site Year: 2015

{ Any help & suggestion is accepted. thanks!
pls see this image [ http://prntscr.com/722hsm ] for my database structure !}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate that you are taking initiative.

Just some modifications:

*Model*

```
<?php
function getData() {
  $siteData = array();
  $this->db->select("name, value");
  $this->db->from('settings');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  if ($query->num_rows()) {
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    // Your data is coming from multiple rows, so need to loop on it.
      $siteData[$row['name']] = $row['value'];
    }
  }
  return $siteData;
}
```

*View:*

```
<h3>Site Information</h3>
<?php foreach($metadata as $dataName => $dataValue) {?>
    <!-- You are getting the names and values in loop, so, 
use it in loop. Also, use ucwords() and str_replace() to beautify your
 output. for more informtion on this, read php.net documentation.
       -->
  <h4><?php echo ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $dataName))?>: <?php echo $dataValue; ?></h4>
<?php }?>
```

**SECOND APPROACH (WITHOUT FOREACH):**

```
<h3>Site Information</h3>
<h4>Site Title: <?php echo $metadata['site_title']; ?></h4>
<h4>Site Description: <?php echo $metadata['site_description']; ?></h4>
<h4>Site keyword: <?php echo $metadata['site_keyword']; ?></h4>
<h4>Site Year: <?php echo $metadata['site_year']; ?></h4>
```

Comment: yes, it does work, but I just want to display the value.

Comment: You are already getting name and value from database, why do want to put hard-coded names against values coming from database?

Comment: sorry Im just a newbie. I'd like to prefer that way.

Comment: @AlexNewbie, welcome. Continue researching and you will become a good programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Just load your model in controller:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Datamodel');
    $data['metadata'] = $this->Datamodel->getData();
    $this->load->view('viewdata', $data);
}
```

try this on your views

```
<h3>Site Information</h3>

      <h4>Site Title: <?php echo $metadata['site_title']; ?></h4>
      <h4>Site Description: <?php echo $metadata['site_description']; ?></h4>
      <h4>Site keyword: <?php echo $metadata['site_keyword']; ?></h4>
      <h4>Site Year: <?php echo $metadata['site_year']; ?></h4>
```

Comment: It shows error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: site_title, site_description, site_keyword, site_year

Comment: It will show error because you are not looping on result data and data is in multiple rows. Please refer my answer below.

Comment: just try `print_r($metadata)` on your view page, and see what did you get.

Comment: I tried your answer Pupil. thanks for that. but I want to get the value only.

Comment: @dinesh i tried your suggestion print_r($metadata), and it shows like this on browser. 

Site Title: Array ( [site_description] => this is my first codeigniter mini app [site_keyword] => first ci app, sample website [site_title] => simple ci app, first app [site_year] => 2015 )

Comment: pleasure all are mine... :)